# Flask file upload is not saving the file

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I've been following a tutorial for a Flask file upload script, which is as follows:

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, flash, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from datetime import datetime
import json
import subprocess
import os
import sys

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/tmp/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt'])

app = Flask('author_script')

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

app.debug = True 

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            flash('File uploaded!', 'success')
            proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {}{} -p n -s n -m num'.format(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            return redirect(url_for('results'))
    return render_template('upload.html')


# This could redirect the user to the stepfunctions page for their AWS account so they can monitor 
# the pipeline progress.
@app.route('/results')
def results():
    return render_template('results.html').
```

**upload.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload Authors List</title>
<h1>Upload Authors List</h1>
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p><input type=file name=file>
     <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

When I upload a proper .txt file and click "Upload", it works, but then when I check the destination folder, the .txt file hasn't been saved there. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you believe that your code works?Can you get a successful message? I just run your code and do some modification and succeed.

Maybe you don't know for sure that where your tmp folder is? How about set `UPLOAD_FOLDER = "."`So you can check the file in your `.py` file 's directory.

Here is my dest folder with two uploaded files:

[image: E:/tmp]

Here is my python file(E:\python_project\test):

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, flash, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from datetime import datetime
import json
import subprocess
import os
import sys

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/tmp/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt','jpg'])

app = Flask('author_script')

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

app.debug = True

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            # flash('File uploaded!', 'success')
            proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {}{} -p n -s n -m num'.format(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    return render_template('upload.html')


# This could redirect the user to the stepfunctions page for their AWS account so they can monitor
# the pipeline progress.
@app.route('/results')
def results():
    return render_template('results.html')

app.run("localhost","8080")
```

Comment: Thanks @pajarnas! I changed the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` to `"."` and it worked!

Comment: @claudiadast congratulations

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure to add the "." before the path if saving in the current directory.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './tmp/'
```

And this shall work!